# Добавление элемента в односвязный список

Tags: c#, односвязный-список

Функция добавления элемента в односвязный список срабатывает не всегда. Объясните пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка.

```
    static Point AddPoint(Point beg, int number, int info)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        //создаем новый элемент 
        Point NewPoint = MakePoint(Convert.ToString(info));
        if (beg == null)//список пустой 
        {
            beg = MakePoint(Convert.ToString(rnd.Next(100, 1000)));
            return beg;
        }
        if (number == 0) //добавление в начало списка 
        {
            NewPoint.next = beg;
            beg = NewPoint;
            return beg;
        }
        //вспом. переменная для прохода по списку 
        Point p = beg;
        //идем по списку до нужного элемента 
        for (int i = 1; i < number - 1 && p != null; i++)
            p = p.next;
        if (p == null)//элемент не найден 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! The size of List less than Number");
            return beg;
        }
        //добавляем новый элемент 
        NewPoint.next = p.next;
        p.next = NewPoint;
        return beg;
    }
```

Comment: "срабатывает не всегда" - было время, когда я наивно считал, что человек, просящий других о помощи, считает себя обязаным предоставить максимум информации. Но нет.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не понимаю почему она не работает. Если бы я знал, я бы не спрашивал.

Comment: Что такое `number`? Когда "срабатывает", а когда "не срабатывает"?

Comment: number - это номер элемента после которого нужно вставить еще 1.
не понимаю от чего зависит, ввожу одни и те же данные.

Comment: Вы программист, или погулять вышли? "Номер" - нумерция начинается с нуля или с единицы?

Comment: По сердечку бьете, молодой человек. С единицы открываю цикл для того чтобы дойти до нужного элемента, но какая разница?
Это же список, в нем нет нумерации как в массиве.

Comment: Диапазон значений параметра `number` - начинается с нуля или с единицы? Спасибо за "молодого человека" :).

Comment: Ну а я хочу предраться к отсутствию валидации `number`). В итоге можно будет передать что-то типа `number = -10`.

Comment: @Igor, я так понял вот эта проверка "if (number == 0)" говорит о том, что с нуля) Но number довольно странный аргумент в принципе. Так как установка по сути не фактическая, а относительная. То есть number == 0 далеко не всегда будет вставлять в начало списка. Он будет банально вставлять перед переданным значением.

Comment: @raspberry367, уберите в цикле for "-1". Он там не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в условии `i < number - 1` в

```
for (int i = 1; i < number - 1 && p != null; i++)
```

Когда мы разберемся со смыслом параметра `number`, станет ясно, что там должно быть.

Принимая замечание @СергейИгнахин в комментариях про `if (number == 0)`, правильное условие должно быть:

`i < number`.